# Undertow (Wildfly8) doesn't handle request parameters

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, wildfly, undertow

I do migration from Jboss AS7 /EAP6 to Wildfly8 and would like to ask here for any hint about undertow, why it doesn't handle request parameters as catalina does in EAP6.

So, I make a call from client to url './client/boom/index.htm?i=1', it comes to an error servlet where I want to get value of parameter `i`:

```
httpServletRequest.getParameter("i");
```

With EAP6 it returns 1, but with Wildfly8 it return null. Why?

Chain of calls is the following (assume basic auth):

1. Call with js to url './client/boom/index.htm?i=1'.
2. Flow doesn't come to subclass of UsernamePasswordLoginModule because authorization required.
3. Flow comes to the error-servlet with

httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code") == 401
httpServletRequest.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.message") == Unauthorized

Here, in the error-servlet I need to get parameter i.

Additional info.

Error-servlet is mapped in this way:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>error</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.error</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
<error-page>
    <error-code>401</error-code>
    <location>/Error.error</location>
</error-page>
```

I have a security domain called 'boom' declared in jboss-web.xml

```
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain>boom</security-domain>
    <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

and in standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
    <security-domains>
        ...
        <security-domain name="boom" cache-type="default">
            <authentication>
                <login-module code="com.boom.security.BoomLoginModule" flag="required"/>
            </authentication>
        </security-domain>
    </security-domains>
</subsystem>
```

Auth method is declared as basic in web.xml.

---

Update. The list of attributes in error servlet is different in EAP6 and WF8

Attributes in WF8:

```
javax.servlet.error.message: Unauthorized
javax.servlet.error.status_code: 401
javax.servlet.error.servlet_name: default
javax.servlet.error.request_uri: /boom-portal/client/boom/index.htm
```

Attributes in EAP6:

```
javax.servlet.forward.request_uri: /boom-portal/client/boom/index.htm
javax.servlet.forward.context_path: /boom-portal
javax.servlet.forward.servlet_path: /client/boom/index.htm
javax.servlet.forward.path_info: /Error.error
javax.servlet.forward.query_string: i=1
javax.servlet.error.message:
javax.servlet.error.status_code: 401
javax.servlet.error.servlet_name: default
javax.servlet.error.request_uri: /boom-portal/client/boom/index.htm
```

Comment: First of all, what framework are you using? Spring MVC or JSF?

Comment: @BuhakeSindi, no framework. Just a post request from js.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this problem is related to [Forwarded multipart requests may lose submitted form parameters](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/UNDERTOW-251)

Try changing the settings of the servlet by adding this annotation [@MultipartConfig](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gmhal.html)

or in the `web.xml` descriptor in this way

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>.....</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>        
    <multipart-config/>
 </servlet>
```

---

**UPDATE**

The problem is the authentication, you are receiving a status code 401:

**401 Status Code Explained**

> The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a
>   WWW-Authenticate header field containing a challenge applicable to the
>   requested resource.

Check how you are making the autentication.

Comment: @QuVad I updated the answer with more information based in your actualization